# How to create a attribute color for NSAttributedString without UIKit or AppKit?

Tags: json, swift

I'm working in one Swift package and I don't may use any Apple libraries, like `AppKit` and `UIKit`. I only can use `Foundation`. In this case, a contribution for [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).

Now, I'm creating a functions for Quick Look. I want show the JSON with pretty print (color and indentation).

But how, to create a attribute color for `NSAttributedString` without `UIColor` or `NSColor`? It's possible?

My attempt:

```
extension JSON: CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable {

    public var customPlaygroundQuickLook: PlaygroundQuickLook {
        let myString = "My String Test"
        let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(
            string: myString,
            attributes: ["NSColor": /* ??? */]
        )

        return .attributedString(myAttrString)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need keys such as `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to set a color (`UIColor` or `NSColor`). And that key itself requires either AppKit or UIKit.

Comment: @rmaddy yep... I replaced `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to `"NSColor"` with the hope of work... do you have any idea to around this problem? I want create a pretty print of the JSON.

Comment: You could work with CoreText then colors and fonts would be as CGColor and CTFont. But of course that isn't just Foundation.